# Jquery Adding text to a span

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-selectors, html

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Classifications" data-valmsg-replace="true">
</span>
```

How can I add text to this span?

What I tried till now is the following:

```
var msg = $('#[data-valmsg-for="Classifications"]').val();
alert(msg);
```

Could some one throw idea on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
$('span[data-valmsg-for="Classifications"]').text('Your Text'); //It wil add text to element

$('span[data-valmsg-for="Classifications"]').text();//It will get your element text
```

In your file get like this

```
var msg = $('span[data-valmsg-for="Classifications"]').text()
alert(msg);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MgrvM/)

Comment: I got the below error while i tried with above code. Unhandled exception at line 1715, column 2 in https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[data-valmsg-for="Classifications"]

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("[data-valmsg-for='Classifications']").text("Some Text");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HK9ZN/)

---

> Note: Above selector will add text to ANY element having a custom
>   attribute of `data-valmsg-for` with a `value` of `Classifications`, so
>   if you want to be that specific, than use
>   `span[data-valmsg-for='Classifications']`